# Microsoft Excel Calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Another question....

I am looking for an Excel formula that will calculate the following...Based of a cells date, I want a cell to return the date of the prior Friday unless the initial cell's date is Saturday then I want the cell to return the date of 2 Friday's prior.

Example...if cell A1 has a date of 10/17/17, then cell A2 will return the date of the prior Friday of 10/13/17. If the date in cell A1 is a Saturday (like 10/21/17) then cell A2 would return the date of the previous Friday (10/13/17 NOT 10/20/17).

This question deals specifically with Friday. My previous post/question was different days. I am not familiar with this complex of a formula. I tried to edit the formula I have for my previous question (=IF(WEEKDAY(A1-2)=1,A1-4,IF(WEEKDAY(A1-2)=7,A1-3,A1-2)), but I am not knowledgeable of this complex of equation.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: No it's not. Suble differences, but requires a very different answer. @Bama, this variation of your previous question gets cumbersome if you try to use nested IF's, like Blackie did for your previous question. The answer day is a different offset for each day of the week, so you'd need 7 nested IFs.  I.e, for Sun Mon, etc., subtract 2,3 etc. Cumbersome.  So it's not surprising that you had trouble modifying the previous answer.  Recognizing that the offset is one more than the number of the day allows the simple formula in Gary's Student's answer.

Comment: It even jumps back a week for Saturday. Really nice.

Answer (score 1):

With a date in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A1),A1-2,A1-3,A1-4,A1-5,A1-6,A1-7,A1-8)
```

*(works like a VLOOKUP)*

or:

```
=A1-WEEKDAY(A1)-1
```

Comment: LOVE the second equation. Simple, elegant, brief. :-)  Definitely worth a +1

Comment: @Bandersnatch  Yes  the second equation is simple....but I still like the first one because it is SO easy to understand and remember....just a translation from the requirement *(in words)* into an Excel formula.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works exactly how I had hoped. Man, I wish I knew those complex equations!  Thank goodness for people such as you to help.